# How do I convert numbers in a list to digits

Tags: python, python-3.x

Could anyone help me with this issue I was trying to search for a solution but could not find it

So I want to convert numbers in a list on python into digits

```
[2, 1, 3, 0] -> 2130
```

How could I do this?

I tried to somehow change it but I just couldn't solve this issue and searched on here to find it but could not find the answer

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: What does "convert into digits" mean? "Digits" isn't a Python data type.

Answer (score 2):

```
def list_to_int(numbers):
  """
  Converts a list of numbers into a single integer.

  Args:
    numbers: A list of integers.

  Returns:
    The integer formed by concatenating the digits of the numbers in the list.
  """
  # Convert each number to a string and concatenate them.
  digits_string = "".join(str(n) for n in numbers)

  # Convert the string to an integer.
  return int(digits_string)
```

```
# Example usage
numbers = [2, 1, 3, 0]
integer = list_to_int(numbers)
print(integer)  # Output: 2130
```

This function first iterates over the list of numbers and converts each number to a string. Then, it concatenates all the strings together to form a single string. Finally, it converts the string to an integer.

Comment: This is clearly not the efficient way to do this task.  Numbers are much easier to work with than strings.  Don't convert back-and-forth unnecessarily.

Comment: @TimRoberts Do you mean not efficient for tiny lists or for large ones? And do you have something more efficient?

Comment: Mozway had the right answer but deleted it.  `sumx = 0` / `for d in x:` / `sumx = sumx * 10 + d`.  Minimum overhead, keeps everything as integers.

Comment: @TimRoberts I just measured with `[1] * 100000`, this was ~28 times faster than Mozway's (0.05 seconds vs 1.4 seconds).

Comment: @TimRoberts And the other answer is so slow that I got tired of waiting and changed down to  `[1] * 20000`, where this took 0.02 seconds, Mozway's took 0.1 seconds, and the other answer took 6.5 seconds. Looks like you were calling the most efficient solution *"clearly not the efficient way"* and didn't say anything about the vastly less efficient answer...

Comment: @TimRoberts For `[1] * 1000000`, this was even ~100 times faster than Mozway's.

Answer (score 0):

Multiply each against a power of ten, then sum

```
x = [2, 1, 3, 0]
y = sum(num * 10 ** i for i, num in enumerate(reversed(x)))
print(x, "==>", y)
```

```
[2, 1, 3, 0] ==> 2130
```